# Text file to CSV with a special condition on the text

Tags: python, csv, text

I have a text file that looks like this

```
******************** extractive sentences ********************

[gold] This is gold sentence

[raw ] This is raw sentence

[rev ] This is rev sentence

[ref ] This is ref sentence

******************** extractive sentences ********************

[gold] This is gold sentence

[raw ] This is raw sentence

[rev ] This is rev sentence

[ref ] This is ref sentence
```

I want to create a CSV, such that all the `[gold]` sentences come
in 1 column and the corresponding `[rev]` sentences come in the second column

I tried reading the file using `pd.read_csv` but it gives error as the sentences can contain ',' and it gives an error like this:

```
'Expected 1 fields in line 11, saw 2'
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: why not open with raw python: open

Comment: yes , i can do that , but after that?

Comment: you can arrange them to a standard csv or tsv file, then open it with pandas

Comment: read as normal file, split to list of lines - you can even convert this list to `dataframe` with one column - and then you can filter lines with `gold` to new column in new `dataframe`, and the same with `raw`, `rev`, `ref`

Comment: always put code, data and error message as text, not image. With data on image we can't use it to create example code - and this way you don't get answer.

Comment: Not an `operating-system` or `machine-learning` question - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing that the data in your .txt file is structured consistently as outlined in your original question, the below solution will pull content from all "`[gold]`" and "`[rev ]`" lines and each pair of these to a .csv file with the appropriate headers.

It achieves this by:

- Reading each line from `input.txt` into a list of strings
- Using `re` to filter this list for lines starting `[gold]`, stripping the leading `[gold]`  and trailing newline character(`\n`) into a new list containing content from all "`[gold]`" lines in the order in which they appear in `input.txt`
- Repeating the above step for lines starting `[rev ]`, filtering these into their own list
- Creating a `pandas.DataFrame` using the lists generated above to populate columns under the corresponding headers (`gold` and `rev`) - with `gold` being the first column and `rev` the second as per your original question
- Writing the `DataFrame` out to `output.csv` by way of `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()`

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    
gold = [ re.sub(r'(\[gold\]\s)|\n', '', l) for l in lines if re.search(r'^\[gold\]', l) ]

rev = [ re.sub(r'(\[rev\s\]\s)|\n', '', l) for l in lines if re.search(r'^\[rev\s\]', l) ]

data = {'gold': gold, 'rev': rev}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

**Important Consideration**

The above solution makes the assumption that for each "`[gold]`" there will be a corresponding "`[rev ]`" - as in the example you provided.

If there are "`[gold]`" lines that do not have corresponding "`[rev ]`" lines - or vice-versa - within each "section" of the .txt file you are reading, the ordering/pairing of rows will be incorrect.

However, if the data in your .txt files is reliably consistent in terms of being structured uniformly as per your original example, this will not be an issue.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, as both the considerations were met